# Can a Druid Wild Shaped as a horse use Horseshoes of Speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, equipment, wild-shape

This would probably work better when the Druid has the option to stay indefinitely in Wild Shape form (usually starting around level 16-18, when a single use of Wild Shape lasts 8-9 hours).

In any case, can a Druid Wild Shaped as a horse equip and use magical horseshoes?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Druids should be able to use magic horseshoes effectively while Wild Shaped

Magic horseshoes like the *horseshoes of speed* specify:

> While all four shoes are affixed to the hooves of a horse or similar creature...

While under the effect of Wild Shape, the druid is in the form of a horse. Even if that does not make the druid an actual horse, it at least makes the druid a "similar creature".

Comment: May be worth answering what happens when they return back to humanoid form. ouch?

Comment: @NautArch Huh. I don't know the answer to that. Asked [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156343/41726)